# Hiding CV from Current Employer

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, jobs

I just heard Careers is going to hide your CV from at least your current employer.  would it be possible to allow us (the programmers waging the wars against the oppressive pointy haired bosses) to input aliases for companies also to prevent them from finding us under different names.  My problem is that my current company has: an official name, a nickname which everyone refers to it as, we were bought out, and our parent company then was bought out.  The company could search careers with any of these four names exposing my search to my boss.

Comment: This is a good point. I work for the parent company of a lot of regional companies and I wouldn't want to appear on any of their searches. +1

Comment: That is to say I work for the Mushroom Kingdom, which reigns over various worlds, castles, dungeons and star roads.

Comment: My fear especially is that for those of who have larger scores (even people who have over 10k is relatively small when compared to the overall pool of programmers in the world), it's really hard for us to hide in plain view.

Comment: I think I came up with a more generic solution: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29424/feature-file-cv-anoymously

Comment: Why would you want to do this? It's not like my employer doesn't already know what my CV looks like

Comment: Because if it's available for employers to search on it, it will tip them off that you are potentially looking for another job.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is implemented already in part -- if *any* of the companies you worked for are a case-insensitive match to the company name of the employer doing the search, you are automatically removed from any of their search results.

This is fully 100% automatic and requires no intervention on your part (other than populating the company names accurately).

Example:

> Company doing the search is **ACME Incorporated**
>
> You've worked for the following companies: **Initech**, **Foo Astronomical Instruments**, and **Acme Incorporated**
>
> You will *not* show up in this company's searches because your employment history includes an exact string match to **ACME Incorporated**.

Usual caveats apply, this is string matching ...

**EDIT**

In Careers 2.0, you can mark yourself as "not actively looking for a job" while still remaining searchable.  The UI makes it very clear to employers that these are just people in our database, not people actively looking for a job.  See *[Not actively seeking work in Careers: I'd like to display this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80893/not-actively-seeking-work-in-careers-id-like-to-display-this)* for more information

Comment: As always, you are the man Jeff.  (btw, congrats on being ranked as one of the top 30 most influential developers).

Comment: Have you considered this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29424/feature-file-cv-anoymously ?

Comment: any progress on the regex mentioned here?

Comment: @David Hypothetically speaking, what if I were looking for a job, but didn't want to reveal that to my employer?

Answer (score 22):

[Podcast 70](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/10/podcast-70) suggests that you'll be able to supply a regular expression to match employers against. That should be flexible enough to do what you need.

Or to put it another way: currently, you have one problem (hiding your CV from your current employer). When you have the option of using regular expressions, [you'll have two problems](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001016.html) :)

Comment: wow I totally missed, that....I must not have enough coffee.

Comment: +1 for relevant quoting of "2 problems" :)

Comment: We are no longer planning on providing a regex, since being able to flag yourself as passively looking for a job should make it less awkward if your current employer finds you.  See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80893/not-actively-seeking-work-in-careers-id-like-to-display-this

Answer (score 6):

Would it not just be easier to allow you to hide your CV from any employer matching a set of terms you can set yourself?

**Edit**: As Jon said, you will be allowed to use the power of **REGULAR EXPRESSIONS** to filter out who you do not want to view your CV.

Comment: +1 if we can use wildcards.

Comment: yeah, that's what I was thinking, sorry I wasn't clear.

Comment: I really love the regular expression bit - you could consider it as a minus first interview question - can you write a regex that effectively filters out your previous employers?

Comment: @DrJokepu: No dice. My employer's name is written in XML.

Answer (score 1):

Will it be possible for me to view other CV's as somebody that looks for a job? How would you then filter out employees I should not see? Overlapping current employers?

My current employer will probably have a normal account and not use the company name. What name he will use will be impossible to foresee. The RegEx has to be very general to do what you ask for, something like .*

Comment: It *better* not be possible for job seekers to view other private CVs - I really don't want folks plagiarizing my awesome works of fiction!

Comment: This should be made into its own question. I want to know!