# How to hide your CV from your employer (or anyone)?

Tags: feature-request, jobs

I know it's been question of providing a regex, but is it implemented yet?

Is it enough?
How can one guarantee that employers/hiring managers would use the common business name?

Will there be some alias detection?

Comment: What if Blue Man Group went under Three Percussion Fellows? How will that work out?

Comment: duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26159/hiding-cv-from-current-employer, which is currently 'status-planned'.

Comment: I *love* Three Percussion Fellows!

Comment: A friend of mind is married to a Percussion Fellow. Their children came out a light shade of blue, with innate rhythmic talents

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. This will be automatic. Any searches from employers you have previously worked for will not "see" you.
2. You can also override it. If you prefer to make it more or less strict, you can manipulate a regex (and use a test form in real time to see how your regex will work).

That said, of course bear in mind that **this is string matching**. So it can only be so accurate..

Comment: On the CV page it mentions that the employer beta will start in a few days.  Can we get a less broad ETA?

Comment: how about 6-8 weeks

Comment: Curious. I can understand hiding it from *current* employer. But why *past* employers?

Comment: In case you hate them.