# Feature: file CV anoymously

Tags: feature-request, jobs

Feature request:
File CV anonymously, or with some personal data excluded. Then I can only reveal myself to potential employers after getting relevant inquiries.

Comment: Great idea - also solves the "I'm open to ideas, but would rather my current employer didn't know" issue

Comment: Right now you can hide most fields.  There are some things you can't hide.  Can you be more explicit as to what you want to hide but can't, other than, "Everything!"

Comment: @Pollyanna, you can hide fields in the public CV, not in the searchable by employers one. I think.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That's an interesting idea, but if I were an employer I would have a hard time justifying paying for a service where I can only see a small bit of anonymous information.  You'd have to unlink the stackoverflow account to really be anonymous, which would eliminate a huge feature of the SO CV search service.  Even if you showed a rounded off reputation score, employers still wouldn't be able to review your questions and answers.

In another sense, it's like looking at advertisements which give only a little information, but force you to contact them for details.  "If you have to ask, you can't afford it" is one perception, the other is that when compared to a search that's full of other candidates who have their information open and available your 'closed' listing looks less attractive.

Hiding form your current employer, however, seems the easiest to resolve, though.  If this CV is 'discovered' then the response is simply, "I keep my resume updated and online regardless of my long term plans.  It's not an intention to leave my current job, it's a pro-active realization that even though I plan on continuing with the company, and even though the company plans on employing me long term, sudden economic shifts may affect both of us.  If anything, it's simply being as prepared as one can be for the unpredictable."

Comment: I agree with most of your points. But 1) some of us don't have personal info on our SO accounts, so we could link even if we had anonymized CVs. 2) Hiring a new employee is different than buying a soft-drink or laundry detergent in that the process cannot be completed (let's say it can't event start) without actually contacting the other party.

Comment: @Fly - so you would concede that an 'anonymous' CV would still be required to link to the SO account?  Keep in mind that careers is employer-centric.  If it's a feature that helps *employers* then it may be implemented, but if it's a feature that only helps potential employees, then it's unlikely to get much attention.  In the worst case if the feature request detracts from the employer experience, then you have to make a very strong case that it's still in the employer's best interest to implement it.

Comment: It helps employers because it will make more potential employees available. Regarding the "employer experience" you are right, but it can be worked out.

Comment: What? You mean potential employers might be reading my Q&As? Oh dear xD

Answer (score 2):

Different answer because it's a fundamentally different approach to the question.

**How is the current system not anonymous?**

Check it out:

http://careers.stackoverflow.com/anonymous

You are literally not required to enter ANY information in any field EXCEPT an email address when filing your CV (which you would need for careers to contact you on a hit anyway).  Your CV is separate from the billing system, so you can enter (or not enter) anything in any field and it won't be associated with whatever you put in the billing information, which won't be shown to employers.

If you require them to contact you prior to gaining access, then why put your sensitive information in the CV at all?  It won't ever be visible to anyone.

Even if you wanted to show up in location specific, or skill-set searches, but make your location/skills unavailable unless contacted, they can run a series of searches to find out where you live or what your skill set is, so there's no point in anonymizing that but also making it available for searches.

As far as I can tell, you can be as anonymous or open as you desire, and require them to contact you for more information.

Please try out the system more fully and describe exactly what you want to make anonymous, but can't currently, or how the anonymous experience could be improved.  Right now you are making a very general request, but as far as I can tell one can immediately fulfill your request right now in the system as it is currently implemented.  You need to be more specific.  Examples would be very helpful.

Comment: The "anonymous" account I made is currently filed as student in Namibia, so it shouldn't soil the employer searches, but just in case I'll be removing it after a few days so it won't clog the system.

Comment: mmmmm.... I guess I already know who is going to get the bounty :)