# Not actively seeking work in Careers: I'd like to display this

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, jobs

SO Careers displays me as "seeking work".

I'm not actually seeking work. I am keeping it on file, and of course if someone wants to contact me, I would like to hear it. But it's not a correct statement that I'm seeking work, and I'd be really quite embarrassed if someone from my company saw that and was like, 'Why is Paul looking for a new job?' I'm pretty happy where I'm at and I'd like Careers to allow me to reflect that

If a checkbox could be put in that said, "not seeking work", I'd really appreciate it!

Comment: Joel did mention the "passively seeking" option in the blog post - http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/02/careers-2-0-launches/ - there's a whole section on it! Maybe you're supposed to clear all the check boxes. But an explicit option would be better.

Comment: @Chrisf: Yeah, uh, how do I figure that one out? He says it'd be cool, but I don't see any option to do it!

Comment: My point exactly. Either it needs to say "clear all options for passive seeking" or have an extra check box.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is done!

To set your Job Search status click the edit link next to your objectives:

[image: Objectives]

And you'll see three new options:

[image]

I think they're pretty self explanatory but here goes anyway:

1. Looking for a job:  You're actively looking for a job and you're ready for employers to contact you.  When employers search for you, they'll find you on the "Active" tab of the search interface.
2. Not looking, but open to being contacted: You aren't actively looking for a job, but you're open to hear from employers who think you're interesting.  When employers search for you, they'll find you on the "Passive" tab of the search interface.
3. Block all messages and searches: You aren't looking for a job and you don't want to hear anything from anyone or show up in any searches.

Comment: Awesome! So glad to hear it!

Comment: Very nice.  The only thing I would add is that, once you make a choice, the choice should show up in the description -- my profile shows what I said about what kind of position I'm interested in, and where, but doesn't show my "not looking, but open" choice.

Comment: @JacobM:  The distinction we make is that when you're active it says: "Actively seeking full-time position".  When you're passive it says: "Interested in full-time position".  Maybe that isn't enough though...

Comment: @Jason: thanks for the quick response.  Now that you say that, it makes sense, but I certainly didn't notice it (of course, I didn't try the two paths).  I'd say it's probably not enough; perhaps "Open to a full-time position" would be more explicit, or perhaps it should actually be a separate sentence (as it is a separate question).

Comment: @JacobM: Oops, I forgot that the other big way we show this distinction is that active seekers show up in one tab of our search interface and passive seekers show up in another, so no one will just happen upon your profile without context...

Comment: Fair point, thanks.  I guess I'm think more about reassurance to the user that the correct value was stored, and also about using the profile as a general resume link (not found through the search interface).

Answer (score 5):

This is coming very soon, probably later this week