# Can we have badge-count displayed on the users page again?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, badges, user-interface, users-page

I found this an interesting second view into someone's participation on a Stack Exchange site. And, y'know, what's the point of earning badges if not to show them off?

The old Users page showed them, but the new reputation-league-style one doesn't. The new display of top tags for the current time period is also great information at that level, and I know there's a balance against presenting an overwhelming amount of detail in a small space. Still, I hope a solution to include both could be found.

EDIT: not just to show off. When I go to the users page, what I generally want is an idea of who the notable users on that site are (see [Aarobot's comment here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81096/week-is-not-a-useful-default-for-the-users-page/81276#81276)). That may or may not correspond to who's been active/helpful *recently*, which is what the new page seems geared at showing. And that's why I miss badges.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like this has been done.  Though, sadly, it doesn't have Adam Davis's suggestion of filtering by time period.

- If the filter is **week/month/quarter/year**, no badges are displayed
- If the filter is **all**, all badges are displayed:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Would be interesting to give badges the same treatment - badges earned this week/month/year/all time.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, this could be an opportunity to improve on the previous display of badges on the users page. I don't really care if someone has Autobiographer or Critic, but I am interested in people who have Legendary or gold tag badges.

Perhaps the user page could display each user's one or two most significant badges, or all significant badges the user earned in the week/month? The latter plan kind of breaks down for the quarter/year rankings.

Comment: One of the problems with focus on those elite badges, such as Legendary or gold tag badges is for at least the next year or so, they will probably only matter on the main trilogy sites.