# Bring badges back to new user page?

Tags: discussion, badges, users-page

The new user page is cool for many reasons, but I miss seeing the badges that the top users have collected.  Can this be brought back, or at least some view where the same info can be seen?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can we have badge-count displayed on the users page again?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81221/can-we-have-badge-count-displayed-on-the-users-page-again)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been done, as I [posted on the other question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81221/can-we-have-badge-count-displayed-on-the-users-page-again/86117#86117) that Popular Demand pointed out.

- If the filter is **week/month/quarter/year**, no badges are displayed
- If the filter is **all**, all badges are displayed:

[image]