# New user page: month should be last 30 days, not "since March 1st GMT 0"

Tags: feature-request, users-page

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Week is not a useful default for the /users page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81096/week-is-not-a-useful-default-for-the-users-page)

For the first few hours the users page is exceptionally chaotic as votes come in for that month.  Same for week, quarter, and year - when the reset point is hit, the page is useless for a little while, and not terribly useful for overall comparison in the long run since it's not a moving average.

It seems that we should be showing reputation earned over the last 7 days/30 days/90 days/365 days rather than having a hard reset point that makes the page nearly useless for several hours, if not a day or two.

Comment: Duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81096/week-is-not-a-useful-default-for-the-users-page