# Add context to "top {x}% this {period}" in user profile

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, reputation-leagues

Currently, under the gigantic Avatar, you see these details

```
{rep}
reputation
top {reverse percentile}% this {period}
{count} views
flag weight {z} (max) << private
got flair?
```

It is hard to make out whether "0.1% this quarter" is better or "0.03% this week".  It also seems to have negative connotations - a percentile report favours the "bigger is better" approach but doing a "top" decreases your "number" as you go higher.

Yes you can click on it to be brought to the /leagues page, but since we're congregating information into this page, it seems appropriate to give it some context

- perhaps a little {?} icon next to the link to show more info, such as "title" (mouseover) tag showing "#146 of 35248"; or
- perhaps just a bracket next to the link (146/35248)

I know someone [asked for 2dp](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81254/top-1-in-profile-page-not-useful-please-dont-count-non-users) precision for the "top {x}% this {period}" feature but even on the largest site (StackOverflow), **it is ridiculous to show a differentiation at 0.01% which equates to 3 users** *(for the quarter, 4 users for overall)*?!

For reference, compare the top 2 users at physics.SE
 
https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/1236/lubos-motl - top 0.58% overall
https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/329/marek - top 2% overall

"Top 1%" and "Top 2%" would suffice?  In fact, "top user overall" and "#2 overall" looks more sexy. *("edge cases" yadda yadda)*

Comment: I see 2dp precision now.

Comment: @jzd Yes, which is why I put the part in bold.. in bold

Comment: @Diago - why remove `discussion`? I have a view but I wanted to see how other people felt as well. I would hate for changes (like the 2dp change) to be implemented on the advice of just one user.

Comment: A feature-request will be viewed by users and discussed, however only one required tagged is encouraged. If you want to discuss first and then make it a feature request, feel free to change the tags. However, Meta standard is to discuss all feature-request, and a feature-request will never be implemented unless it has enough votes to get the development teams attention.