# Delete old, unloved, users

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, user-accounts, spam

I've been putting some thought into [Is spam in the "about me" field a reason to worry?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105218/is-spam-in-the-about-me-field-a-reason-to-worry), and particularly the statement at the top of the accepted answer:

> The trick is *finding* these spam profile user accounts, really.

I agree, there doesn't seem to be any reliable metric unless you resort to regular expressions, *sigh*, which isn't ever going to work correctly.

My proposal is that all users that:

- Have never voted
- Have never posted
- Haven't visited in a year
- Have only ever visited on the day the created their account, and...
- Have filled something in the "About Me" or "Website" fields.

should get automatically deleted in the same way that old, unanswered, unloved [questions do.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006/179419). This seems a little harsh I know but bear with me.

As of the last data.SE refresh there were [6,521 users on Stack Overflow](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/79423/users-whove-never-interacted-with-the-site-and-have-only-ever-logged-on-once) who fulfil these criteria. Obviously, not all of these are there only to a place for spam to reside and a glance at the "About Me" field seems to indicate that the majority of them are normal people.

However, they're certainly not doing anything useful and [scrolling through](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/79424/users-whove-never-interacted-with-the-site-and-have-only-ever-logged-on-once) also throws up a fair amount of "people" who are just a URL pointing to a company and a few "people" whose "About Me" field is pure spam.

I would almost be tempted to remove the condition about visiting on a single day, which raises the number to [16,073 users](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/79426/number-of-users-whove-never-interacted-and-have-filled-in-some-profile-info), but I'm not certain about it.

Removing these users will not affect the headline count, which is obviously important to Stack Exchange; but it will help with a clean-up of these users. Those people who are registered aren't going to miss their account and as there's a relatively low barrier to entry it isn't going to be difficult for them to re-register.

I'm not even sure that re-registering would be required; this could easily be implemented by not displaying / soft deleting users that fulfil this criteria but still enabling them to log in thereby "reactivating" the account.

Comment: It's [56,829](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/79426/number-of-users-whove-never-interacted-and-have-filled-in-some-profile-info) now instead of 16,073.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[We did this for years...](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/02/when-is-an-account-abandoned/)

...but it turns out there are [entirely too many unloved users for us to delete them all](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48262/when-will-inactive-accounts-be-deleted/48263#48263); user deletion is a "heavy" operation on these sites, as we actually scrub a great deal of information associated with users (vs. just setting a "deleted" flag as we do for deleted posts).

Thus, the unloved must necessarily request deletion on their own.

Comment: Maybe there should be a [meta-tag:status-you-are-behind] tag.

Comment: @Myst `status-duh`?

Comment: By _"only a fraction of these actually get deleted on each pass."_ do you mean that there is a limit to the number of users who get deleted each time?

Comment: Yes, @Ben. I forget the number, but it is capped.

Comment: So, if I were to change the title to "Delete old, unloved, users better" this would no longer be status-completed?

Comment: You should probably post that separately, @Ben - it sounds more like a bug report.

Comment: I thought the user are never deleted based on inactivity or low rep if they have voted at least 1 time... Wasn't that the initial status?

Comment: Unregistered users and users with 1 rep can't vote, @РСТȢѸФХѾЦЧШЩЪЫЬѢѤЮѦѪѨѬѠѺѮѰѲѴ

Comment: related: [Spam Profiles are getting my goat. Could we have better tools for mods to deal with profile spam?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/303746/165773) Looks like spammers have found an unlimited, permanent repository for their content in Stack Exchange profile pages