# How long does it take for reputation on Stack Overflow Careers to be updated?

Tags: discussion, reputation, jobs, caching

Just curious how this works:

My Stack Overflow reputation on my Stack Overflow CV shows an amount X, which is less than my actual Stack Overflow reputation Y. It's been this way for a few days. In addition, some of my 'favorite answers' on my CV have a lower # of votes than they do in reality.

How long does it take for this (I assume cached) value to be updated?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Short Version: Yeah, we're out of date.  I'm working over the next couple of days to stabilize the updates process.

How it works: Essentially, we slurp down all the data we need to keep your accounts and answers up to date from the public API every day and what I originally wrote during our mad dash to the finish line is a little error prone.  Couple that with the search rewrite I had to do to fix [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80893/not-actively-seeking-work-in-careers-id-like-to-display-this) and I just haven't gotten to shoring it up yet.  It'll stabilize over the next week and updates should only lag by about a day.

Comment: Cool! I don't think its a big deal that it is a little out of date, was just wondering why my rep wasn't showing ;-) Thanks for the quick and detailed response!

Comment: Does this issue still exist? Because i i am facign same issue in my Career 2.0 profile after linking. Career.StackOverFlow.REP<StackOverFlow.PROFILE.REP

Comment: I'm wondering the same thing. It's been over a week since my Careers rep updated.

Comment: @Calvin guess not relevant by now, but anyway this is most likely due to bug with the account, merging etc, better start a new bug report here on MSE.