# How often information on careers.stackoverflow.com updates?

Tags: support, reputation, jobs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How long does it take for reputation on Stack Overflow Careers to be updated?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81536/how-long-does-it-take-for-reputation-on-stack-overflow-careers-to-be-updated)

My rep on stackoverflow is now 1.150, careers.stackoverflow.com still displays 906 (about 1 week). So, how long careers.stackoverflow.com caches this information?

Comment: So, only I who is unhappy? :) Yes. It's a duplicate, apparently  (sorry for that - I really searched for this question - don't know how I did not notice).