# Why are reputation points of SE sites, not getting updated on Careers.SO profile?

Tags: support, reputation, jobs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How long does it take for reputation on Stack Overflow Careers to be updated?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81536/how-long-does-it-take-for-reputation-on-stack-overflow-careers-to-be-updated)

Is there a (long) delay when change in rep points are reflected on Career.SO or do we manually have to refresh rep points somewhere?

Or is this just happening with me (based on some algorithm?)

May be this delay is by design, but I was just wondering whether having a rep recalc link like we have for [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/reputation) will be any good?

Comment: Caching. Patience.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81536/how-long-does-it-take-for-reputation-on-stack-overflow-careers-to-be-updated