# My reputation on Stack Overflow is not updated in Careers 2.0

Tags: support, stack-overflow, reputation, jobs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How long does it take for reputation on Stack Overflow Careers to be updated?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81536/how-long-does-it-take-for-reputation-on-stack-overflow-careers-to-be-updated)

I have created my profile in Careers 2.0. But my reputation is not updated. It shows 392 reputation while it is the reputation when I created the profile. Is there any way to update it? This is my [Careers 2.0 profile](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/neerajr) and here is my [Stack Overflow profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1429828/neeraj)

Comment: I think that instead this is merely referring to a caching issue where the SO reputation is not updated yet when visiting the career 2.0 profile

Comment: Give it at least a day (24h) to update. I believe reputation is cached heavily on SE, and may take some time to update.

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall : Ok, I updated 16 hrs ago. After 24hrs, i will check it again.

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81536/how-long-does-it-take-for-reputation-on-stack-overflow-careers-to-be-updated.

Comment: @Neeraj: Any your reputation is now updated :)

Comment: @hims056 yeah, updated. Should i have to delete this question?

Comment: @Neeraj :) Don't delete your question. It could help the future visitors and also if you delete the question, you will get a bit close to get a ban from asking questions(not exactly with a single question deletion).

Comment: @Neeraj: No. keep it open. Devs may find this useful if there is some bug.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Everything looks fine here. As stated [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81536/how-long-does-it-take-for-reputation-on-stack-overflow-careers-to-be-updated) reputation for accounts on your careers profile updates once a day.

Since you asked the question we've updated your rep, and since we updated your rep you got at least 120 more (WOOT!) which will show up on careers profile tomorrow.