# Why doesn't reputation update on my Careers page?

Tags: support, status-completed, reputation, jobs

This is not a duplicate of [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/154993/184589) or [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/81536/184589). I mean, it is, but the solutions/answers don't really match the current problem.

So, I have a Careers profile that includes my SO reputation. But the reputation mentioned there is the one I had over 3 weeks ago (May 5th). I don't remember exactly, but it may be the date when I first selected for my SO profile to be listed there.

I don't know exactly where Careers gets the information from. So, to exclude the possibility that it gets it from Data.SE, I did a query there and the result differs between the two.

Why isn't the reputation updated ? Or, if it is, why is it done so rarely ?

PS: It doesn't really affect me in any significant way, but it may be a bug somewhere, so I thought I'd ask / report it.

Comment: My Careers profile suffers from this same bug.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That has been taken care of. I accidentally slowed down the pace at which reps are synchronized while testing it locally; at the new pace it would take ~100 days to process all of them.  It's been changed so it should sync everyone about every 8 hours now. :D

Comment: Awesome, thanks. I'll accept your answer soon :)

Answer (score 2):

Not a duplicate, this is the 4th or so report I've gotten in 2 days and it looks like even my rep is out of date.  Looking into it.